How to make Blender open Visual Studio on __debugbreak() instead of crashing?
Usually when I execute in system some python code that's using compiled .pyd module with __debugbreak() c++ command it shows window suggesting to open Visual Studio:

But when I run similar code in Blender it crashes EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT.
Error   : EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
Address : 0x00007FFB99F2426A
Module  : _ifcopenshell_wrapper.pyd
Thread  : 000024cc

Any way to avoid it and start Visual Studio instead? Already tried to start Blender with --debug / --debug-all.
